# SQL Server 2012: Combine two rows into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot

I have this in my table

```
ID     Routing      
01     WFM
01     ESCALATE
02     WFM
02     ESCALATE
```

And I would like to display (SQL SELECT query) to something like below

```
ID     Routing1  Routing2      
01     WFM        ESCALATE
02     WFM        ESCALATE
```

Comment: Sounds remotely like a case for `PIVOT` (but not quite). A larger example table would help to make clearer the logic behind the desired transformation.

Comment: i think you can perform a self join and then filter it to get the result

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.id,a.routing as routing1,b.routing as routing2 
from table1 as a join table1 as b 
on
a.id=b.id
```

This can be your base query.

To achieve your result. YOu can use  something like.

```
select id,routing1,routing2 
from (select a.id,a.routing as routing1,b.routing as routing2 
from table1 as a join table1 as b 
on
a.id=b.id)
where routing1 != routing2;
```

I think you can just add the a.routing !=b.routing to the base query and not deal with the second query

Answer (score 0):

```
 select id, max(routing) as routing1, 
            (select min(routing) from route r2 where r2.id = r1.id) as routing2
    from route r1
    group by id
```

This works perfectly, only when you have 2 records with sameid.